# Data Entry mySQL truncated when using %C3 special character

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I have the following query:

```
 INSERT INTO `poll` (`pollId`, `groupId`, `creatorUserId`, `createdDateTime`, 
                     `lastVoteDateTime`, `pollQuestion`, `pollOption`) 
              VALUES (NULL, '24', '73', '2014-02-18 21:27:12', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                      '1111111111', '222222222222Ã223442')
```

**when execute this query using php the data for pollOption inserted truncated like this 222222222222 without Ã223442;**

**but when execute it in myManager the data for pollOption inserted successfully "222222222222Ã223442";**

NOTE:
database and table and fields all of them UTF-8.
php file is ANSI encoding

PHP CODE:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
require_once "config.php";
error_reporting(0);
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$response="";
if(isset($_REQUEST['userId']))
{
$userId=$_REQUEST['userId'];
$groupId=$_REQUEST['groupId'];
$pollQuestion=$_REQUEST['pollQuestion'];
$pollOptions=rawurldecode(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['pollOptions'])); 

$insertPoll=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `poll` 
                     (`pollId`, `groupId`, `creatorUserId`, 
                      `createdDateTime`, `lastVoteDateTime`, `pollQuestion`, `pollOption`) 
               VALUES (NULL, '$groupId', '$userId', '$date', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                      '$pollQuestion', '$pollOptions')") or die(mysql_error());   
         echo("INSERT INTO `poll` 
                       (`pollId`, `groupId`, `creatorUserId`, `createdDateTime`, 
                        `lastVoteDateTime`, `pollQuestion`, `pollOption`) 
                       VALUES (NULL, '$groupId', '$userId', '$date', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                        $pollQuestion', '$pollOptions')");
if($insertPoll)
{
    $response.='{"success":"0","message":"successfully poll posted"}';

}else
{
    $response.='{"success":"1","message":"something went wrong"}';
}


echo $response;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That Ã in your php file is surely a latin-1 Ã and not an UTF-8 Ã. When presented with latin-1 extended chars, linux mysql will just truncate when it finds the first incorrect character, while windows mysql will give you an error.

Use utf8_encode in your offending field if it is coming in latin-1:

```
$insertPoll=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `poll` 
                     (`pollId`, `groupId`, `creatorUserId`, 
                      `createdDateTime`, `lastVoteDateTime`, `pollQuestion`, `pollOption`) 
               VALUES (NULL, '$groupId', '$userId', '$date', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
                      '$pollQuestion', '".utf8_encode($pollOptions)."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Edit: investigating a little more, the error doesn't depend on linux/windows, but on whether strict mode is enabled or not. Sorry!.

In any case, using correct UTF-8 will solve your problem.